# E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, image, nullpointerexception, bitmapfactory

I want to upload images from gallery to sever and send image_url to keep in database for retrieving them to show again in android. By the way, I have no idea that how to start it.

Now I'm starting and trying to apply the code from here : https://trinitytuts.com/capture-image-upload-server-android/

This is my new code :

```
package com.theclubprogramming.clickanduploadpic;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    Button btpic, btnup;
    private Uri fileUri;
    String picturePath;
    //File pictureFile;
    Uri selectedImage;
    Bitmap photo;
    String ba1;
    public static String URL = "http://192.168.1.39/picUp/index.php";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        btpic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cpic);
        btpic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clickpic();
            }
        });

        btnup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.up);
        btnup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                upload();
            }
        });
    }

    private void upload() {
        // Image location URL
        Log.e("path", "----------------" + picturePath);

        // Image
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
        byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
        ba1 = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);

        Log.e("base64", "-----" + ba1);

        // Upload image to server
        new uploadToServer().execute();

    }

    private void clickpic() {
        // Check Camera
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // Open default camera
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

            // start the image capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Camera not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            selectedImage = data.getData();
            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            // Cursor to get image uri to display

            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            //fix
            //pictureFile = new File(cursor.getString(columnIndex));
            //picturePath = pictureFile.getAbsolutePath();
            //cursor.close();

            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Imageprev);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }

    public class uploadToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd.setMessage("Wait image uploading!");
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("base64", ba1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ImageName", System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"));
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String st = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.v("log_tag", "In the try Loop" + st);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }
            return "Success";

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.hide();
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

This is logcat error :

```
12-28 08:05:12.171 2422-2422/com.theclubprogramming.clickanduploadpic E/path: ----------------null
12-28 08:05:12.171 2422-2422/com.theclubprogramming.clickanduploadpic E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 08:05:12.175 2422-2422/com.theclubprogramming.clickanduploadpic D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-28 08:05:12.175 2422-2422/com.theclubprogramming.clickanduploadpic W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa619e908)
12-28 08:05:12.183 2422-2422/com.theclubprogramming.clickanduploadpic E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                            at com.theclubprogramming.clickanduploadpic.MyActivity.upload(MyActivity.java:73)
                                                                                            at com.theclubprogramming.clickanduploadpic.MyActivity.access$100(MyActivity.java:34)
                                                                                            at com.theclubprogramming.clickanduploadpic.MyActivity$2.onClick(MyActivity.java:61)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 08:05:12.191 2422-2426/com.theclubprogramming.clickanduploadpic D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 8% free 2644K/2860K, paused 2ms+0ms, total 8ms
12-28 08:05:15.203 2422-2422/com.theclubprogramming.clickanduploadpic I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2422 SIG: 9
```

Could you tell me how to fix it? Thank you for attention.

Comment: Tunaki, the question that you suggest is very overload information for my question. Please give me better detail. I have to fix this problem to graduate in this year. I don't have enough time for checking all.

Comment: while calling intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); you are passing fileUri as null because you are not initializing fileUri variable. Either give a valid fileUri and use the same uri inside onActivityResult() instead getting it from intent. Or you can directly call camera via Intent cameraIntent=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); without passing any extra fileUri

Comment: ankit aggarwal, I initialized fileUri variable at first if you can see it. this line " private Uri fileUri; " is under MainActivity class. So, I tried the way that you advise for me, but it doesn't work. CAMERA_REQUEST variable is unknown.

Comment: as i can see from your activity class posted above you are just declaring it not giving any valid file path to it. CAMERA_REQUEST is your request code to identify your request. you can assign it any value 1,2,3 etc. and when you get a callback inside onActivityResult() there just have a check whether the callback is for the same request code or not. For further help check this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html